# Can't import 'com.google.android.maps'

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gradle

I'm working with a library which use 'MapActivity' of the package 'com.google.android.maps' but this package could not be resolved. I use Android studio. This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pl.llp.aircasting"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7_r1'
compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:1.1'
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:2.0-no_aop'
compile "com.google.guava:guava:16+"
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.2.3'
}
```

Comment: is it on your (Class)Path?

Comment: i think no. I don't config a classpath

Comment: but i already add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7_r1' in build.gradle

Comment: If you are using Maven or Gradle check whether the dependency is being added to the classpath, if not you need to download the respective jar.

Comment: well, there's your problem. did you think an import statement would look the entire internet for the libraries you request?

Comment: So i have downloaded the source code of Aircasting and i import this in android studio.... and Aircasting use com.google.android.maps.MapActivity but this could not be resolved. In fact, no, I only thought that I needed to mention the dependencies needed in build.gradle.

Comment: Click in your code on MapActivity, then <ALT>+<ENTER> -> what happens?

Comment: @nicolallias it says create class MapActivity... but the problem is the package com.google.android.maps (maps could not be resolved) :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this line present in your build.gradle file ?

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.+'

Comment: i put compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7_r1'

Comment: If possible, share your build.gradle file

Comment: ok, I modified the post.please see on the post the build.gradle

Comment: Can you add below block to your gradle file, 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can you change com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7_r1 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0

Comment: I do some research on the internet and i think it related about the targetsdkversion ... it need a google apis version

Comment: Target has nothing to do with symbols resolution, Confirm me if that is working for you.

Comment: i change the compiledSdkVersion to 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your map dependency from**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7_r1'
```

**to**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```